# Invoke RestMethod shows no error but does not upload file

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3, upload

I have a powershell script that I am running through ExtendScript (Photoshop) in order to upload files to an s3 bucket.
I have this code to upload files to an aws s3 bucket.
However, it only works for smaller files (works on a 50mb file)
But does not work on a 140mb file. Shows no error but the file is not uploaded.
Any ideas?

```
$_rawfilename = 'C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Temp/Filled_Albedo.exr'
$folder = 'seam-removal'
$filename = 'Filled_Albedo.exr'
$keyFile = ($folder+ '/' + $filename)
$service = 's3'
$bucket = '**'
$region = 'us-west-2'
$host1 = $bucket + '.s3'  + '.amazonaws.com'
$access_key = '**'
$secret_key = '**'
$br = [regex]::Unescape('\u000a')
function HmacSHA256($message, $secret) {
    $hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
    $hmacsha.key = $secret
    $signature = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($message))
    return $signature
}

function getSignatureKey($key, $dateStamp, $regionName, $serviceName) {
    $kSecret = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(('AWS4' + $key).toCharArray())
    $kDate = HmacSHA256 $dateStamp $kSecret
    $kRegion = HmacSHA256 $regionName $kDate
    $kService = HmacSHA256 $serviceName $kRegion
    $kSigning = HmacSHA256 'aws4_request' $kService

    return $kSigning
}

function hash($request) {
    $hasher = [System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256]::Create()
    $content = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($request)
    $bytes = $hasher.ComputeHash($content)
    return ($bytes | ForEach-Object ToString x2) -join ''
}
function requestBuilder($method, $key) {

    $now = [DateTime]::UtcNow
    $amz_date = $now.ToString('yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ')
    $datestamp = $now.ToString('yyyyMMdd')

    $signed_headers = 'host'
    $credential_scope = $datestamp + '/' + $region + '/' + $service + '/' + 'aws4_request'

    $canonical_querystring = ''
    $canonical_querystring = 'X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
    $canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Credential=' + [uri]::EscapeDataString(($access_key + '/' + $credential_scope))
    $canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Date=' + $amz_date
    $canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Expires=86400'
    $canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=' + $signed_headers

    $canonical_headers = 'host:' + $host1 + $br

    $canonical_request = $method + $br
    $canonical_request += '/' + $key + $br
    $canonical_request += $canonical_querystring + $br
    $canonical_request += $canonical_headers + $br
    $canonical_request += $signed_headers + $br
    $canonical_request += 'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD'

    $algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'

    $canonical_request_hash = hash -request $canonical_request
    $string_to_sign = $algorithm + $br
    $string_to_sign += $amz_date + $br
    $string_to_sign += $credential_scope + $br
    $string_to_sign += $canonical_request_hash

    $signing_key = getSignatureKey $secret_key $datestamp $region $service
    $signature =  HmacSHA256 -secret $signing_key -message $string_to_sign
    $signature = ($signature|ForEach-Object ToString x2) -join ''

    $canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Signature=' + $signature

    $request_url = 'http://' + $host1 + '/' + $key + '?' + $canonical_querystring
    Write-Host $request_url
    return $request_url
}
#C# class to create callback
$code = @"
public class SSLHandler
{
    public static System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback GetSSLHandler()
    {

        return new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback((sender, certificate, chain, policyErrors) => { return true; });
    }

}
"@

#compile the class
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code

#disable checks using new class
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = [SSLHandler]::GetSSLHandler()
#do the request
try
{
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri (requestBuilder 'PUT' $keyFile) -InFile $_rawfilename
} catch {
    # do something
} finally {
   #enable checks again
   [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {true}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting [`$ErrorActionPreference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.2#erroractionpreference) to `Stop`?

Comment: What would that do? Sorry, I did not write this code myself. I'm a novice.

Comment: I linked the documentation, have a read. Basically, it controls errors that your code could generate. By default, it is set to `Continue` and if you encounter an error, the code simply ignores it and continues, thus you won't be able to `catch` it.

Comment: No luck, still won't upload.

Comment: It isn't about uploading, but trying to get an error. In the catch block, write `Write-Host $_`

Comment: Try adding `-Verbose` to the `Invoke-RestMethod` call, it might show you the exact size of the request stream...

Comment: I have added *Write-Host $_ in the catch block, and added -Verbose to the call, however I get nothing except this: `VERBOSE: PUT http://quixel-ml-team-data.s3.amazonaws.com/seam-removal/Original 
Albedo.exr?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAYZL7ANTUBCWOS5E7/20220829/us-west-2/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220829T075702Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=1abd336df943d 
8077a1eba535f1699d61c5c2fd223f2917ec229400d9af823c3 with -1-byte payload`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started working after making the changes suggested in the above comments (verbose and write host).